# FASTAPI: Only allow requests from an app in another container

Tags: python, fastapi

I can't figure out what seems a trivial problem:

I have a dockerized FastAPI service. It consists of 2 containers: serviceA and serviceB.

I want serviceB to be available only for serviceA, and not to all the world.

I tried this:

```
from fastapi.middleware.trustedhost import TrustedHostMiddleware


def get_application():
    app = FastAPI(title=server_config.PROJECT_NAME, version=server_config.VERSION)

    app.add_middleware( TrustedHostMiddleware, allowed_hosts=["http://serviceA"] )

    return app


# Connect to DB
app = get_application()
```

But it doesn't work, requests coming from serviceA are blocked. I also tried localhost, serviceA:8000 etc. but nothing works...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is one way to achieve it, but `http://serviceA` won't work, it expects a hostname. Now as you mentioned, you might have tried and this did not work. That's because it depends on what your machine presents itself as.   make sure you have the correct hostname for the `serviceA`.

Comment: thanks! could you elaborate more on "make sure you have the correct hostname for "?  Also, are you seggesting there are other/better ways to achieve the same result?

Comment: Something quick and dirty would be to remove the restriction on host that you have,  check the headers and figure out what the container that runs `serviceA` presents itself as and add the host to the `allowed_hosts` for `serviceB`. Yes, there are other ways to achieve what you are trying to do, but it will depend on many things. What you are doing is not unreasonable. Just make sure you allow the correct hostname and you make it parametrizable if needed.